# what is s_gi() function in scriptlet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, web-applications

I am studying some source code, it's a web app using JSPs and Servlets.
Inside one scriptlet, there is some javascript code containing this function

```
<%
String callSCode = request.getSession().getAttribute("callSCode");
%>
var s=s_gi('<%=callSCode%>');
```

what is **s_gi** doing?

Comment: It's not *in* the scriptlet, it's after it, in the raw text that will be sent with the response. Clearly that raw text is in a JavaScript `script` element. A trivial web search brings up https://webanalyticsfordevelopers.com/2013/12/17/s_gi-and-tracking-links/ suggesting it's part of your analytics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no way to know what `s_gi` is doing from the context you have given.